# How to typecast an imported class from an sql table

Tags: c#, linq

I tried searching  here first but i couldn't find an answer, even though its probably already out there.

I am using LINQ to get a class User from a db table for a login system i am making for a project.

the specific code is:

```
    public User GetUser(string username)
    {
        var user = from x in db.User
                   where x.Login == username
                   select x;

        return (User)user;
    }
```

The problem is that apparently I am not allowed to typecast the output as (User)

the User class is defined as:

```
    class User
    {
    EntitySet<Donation> donationList = new EntitySet<Donation>();
    EntityRef<Totals> totals = new EntityRef<Totals>();
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Firstname {get; set;}
    [Column]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Streetname { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int CPRNumber { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Bloodtype { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public DateTime NextPlasmaDonation { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public DateTime NextWholeBloodDonation { get; set; }
    [Association(Name = "User_Donation", IsForeignKey = true, Storage="donationList", ThisKey = "UserId", OtherKey = "UserId")]
    public ICollection<Donation> DonationList
    {
        get { return this.donationList; }
        set { this.donationList.Assign(value); }
    }
    }
```

Is anymore information needed to help me solve this?

edit: the specific error given is:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ProjektBlodbank.exe

Additional information: An object of the type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[ProjektBlodbank.Business.User]' can not be converted to the type 'ProjektBlodbank.Business.User'.

Comment: So obviously the type contained by `db.User` is not the `User` class you showed. What type is it instead?

Comment: db.User is a table in my db containing the Columns mentioned above...

Comment: ah, nevermind, Marko and Wazner are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ does not know that Login makes an User unique, so the query you execute will return an `IQueryable<User>`. This means the query could possibly return multiple users. Below are possible solutions to your problem.

**If the user will always exist**
If you are certain only 1 row is returned, you could do your cast as follows:

```
return user.Single();
```

**If the user might exist, but it's not certain.**
If you are uncertain: for example the user might not exist, you would want to use `SingleOrDefault`.

```
return user.SingleOrDefault();
```

This will return `null` if the user could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Select only one, not the complete colletction.

```
public User GetUser(string username)
{
    var user = (from x in db.User
               where x.Login == username
               select x).SingleOrDefault();

    return (User)user;
}
```

Comment: This will throw an `Exception` if the user does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
    public User GetUser(string username)
    {
        var user = (from x in db.User
                   where x.Login == username
                   select x).FirstOrDefault();

        return (User)user;
    }
```